# helper.Action: problem with formatting an URL based on route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]

I navigate to a 'detail' page with the id 10.000 as you can see on the picture above.

On this page, I have a back button (named 'retour' in french).

[image]

I need to format the URL for this button to navigate back to the search page.

[image]

I have an object populated with criteria (picture above). As you can see, IdAffaire is null.

**BUT** when the URL is formatted with the helper.Action method, the IdAffaire is initialized with the value 10.000 retrieved from the URL of the page!! This is a behaviour of the routing system.

"The routing system is keen to make a match against a route, to the extent that it will reuse segment variable values from the incoming URL."

[image]

This behaviour is problematic for me. I hope you know what I mean, it is difficult to explain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: here is the route causing the problem:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Affaire Detail",                                               // Route name
        "{controller}/Detail/{IdAffaire}",                              // URL with parameters
        new { action = "Detail" },                                      // Parameter defaults
        new { controller = "Affaire" }                                  // Contraints
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behavior and is by design. You can workaround it by explicitly setting values:

```
helper.Action("SearchAffaires", "Affaire", new { 
    IdAffaire = "",  
    page = sessionWrapper.SearchCriteriaAffaire.Page, 
    pageSize = sessionWrapper.SearchCriteriaAffaire.PageSize,
    // pass any other parameter that your SearchAffaires action might require
})
```

Comment: I try your solution (explicitly setting values) but in my case, IdAffaire is null. If I explicitly set null on IdAffaire, the routing will reuse the value from the incoming URL. So it don't works...unfortunately

Comment: @Bronzato, sorry I made a mistake in my post. Setting `IdAffaire = null` in the anonymous object won't even compile :-) It should be `IdAffaire = ""`. Tested and it worked. Also notice that I am using an anonymous object as the third argument of the Action helper, I am not passing directly the `sessionWrapper.SearchCriteriaAffaire` as you did in your question.

Comment: I try with IdAffaire = "" (anonymous object) but it don't works. The routing system is still reusing value from the incoming URL. Maybe you tested successfully but your incoming URL didn't contain any IdAffaire parameter...

Comment: @Bronzato, my testing url did contain IdAffaire parameter. If you have the possibility to send me a sample project illustrating the problem I will be happy to take a look at what might be wrong with it.

Comment: I know why you tested successfully and not me: I added routes to my schema. I comment all my custom routes and it works. Now the question is: why my routes are causing this problem?

Comment: @Bronzato, you expect me knowing which routes you have defined by telepathy?

Comment: by telepathy, certainly not :) I updated my question to show you the route causing the problem

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce the issue.